# recursive function $F(n)=n\cdot F(n-1)$

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to check if my solution is correct:

I need to find a recursive function for organizing $n$ people in a row.

The function I got is $F(n)=n\cdot F(n-1)$ while $F(0)=1$. Also I want to prove that $F(n)=n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot ... \cdot 1$

Is it correct?

Comment: $F(n)=nF(n-1)=n(n-1)F(n-2)=n(n-1)(n-2)F(n-3)$. Can you finish the proof?

Comment: do you know about the factorial? and about induction?

Comment: so it will be $F(n)=n!$?

Comment: You can prove by induction.

Comment: yes, thank you, I did